# Which Google Domain Verification APIs to use for Pub/Sub Domain Verification?

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-api, google-cloud-platform

I have this code, which gets a Domain token and verifies a domain with google using the [Site Verification API](https://developers.google.com/site-verification/v1/):

```
const auth = await this.gcp.getApplicationCredential(accountId, projectId,[
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/siteverification',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/siteverification.verify_only'     
]);
const siteVerification = this.google.siteVerification({
    version: 'v1',
    auth
});      
const res = await siteVerification.webResource.getToken({
    requestBody: {
        verificationMethod: "FILE",
        site: {
            identifier: siteUrl,
            type: "SITE"
        }
    }
});
await siteVerification.webResource.insert({
   verificationMethod: "FILE",
   requestBody: {
       site: {
           identifier: siteUrl,
           type: "SITE",
        },
   }
});
```

After I do this I can see the site is verified in the UI:
[image]

Then I use the [Search Console API](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/) to add the site to search console:

```
const auth = await this.gcp.getApplicationCredential(accountId, projectId,[
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters'  
]);
const webVerification = this.google.webmasters({
    version: 'v3',
     auth
});
await webVerification.sites.add({
    siteUrl
});
```

When I do a GET against the API like this:

```
const site = await webVerification.sites.get({
    siteUrl
});
```

I can see that my API call was successful:

```
{
   “siteUrl”: “https://fakewebsite.com/“,
   “permissionLevel”: “siteOwner”
}
```

*So here is the problem:* *When I look at the UI in my project I don't see the verification:*
[image]
*And when I try to create a subscription with a push endpoint my API call fails:*

```
await pubsub.projects.subscriptions.create({
    name: subscription,
    requestBody: {
        topic: topicName,
        pushConfig: {
            pushEndpoint
        },
    }
});
```

*With this error:*

```
{"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"The supplied HTTP URL is not registered in the subscription's parent project (url=\"https://fakewebsite.com/c050d966-b62c-4cc8-9cc9-d431e8d8f14c/suggestions\", project_id=\"9999999999\").
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer for this question from the Google Iam Engineering team today. There is currently no API for Domain Verification in Google Cloud. It has to be done via the UI. They did file a feature request for me so I'll update if this becomes available.